# JOOQ - missing dialects

Tags: java, jooq

I wonder, how is that possible that when I'm looking onto the javadoc for `jooq:3.13.5`, the *SQLDialect* enum contains the full list of the possible sql dialects (speaking about [this](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.13.x/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html)). But when I'm adding this dependency to my project's pom.xml (or even simply linking `jooq-3.13.5.jar` out of the Maven, because I saw that when Maven is taking care of it, the *SQLDialect* is loaded from `jooq-3.13.5-sources.jar` lib when this enum is also available straightly from the `jooq-3.13.5.jar` lib), the *SQLDialect* enum seems to be different and/or incomplete. This is the list of the dialects from the enum that belongs to the mentioned library:

[image]

What can be wrong here? Maybe it seems to be stupid as a question, but I have no idea what can be wrong here - I'm looking at the documentation, where the version is mentioned as `3.13.5`, then I'm getting the dependency from the Maven's repository and the content of the library seems to be a little bit different. I've also tried to fire `mvn dependency:tree` and everything is fine. Situation is exactly the same considering versions: `3.13.4`, `3.13.3`, `3.13.2`, `3.13.1`, `3.13.0`.

To be clear - I'm looking here for two dialects - for Oracle 12c and for SQLServer 2017.

Comment: Is 3.13.5 the latest of the 3.13.x versions?

Comment: Actually I think this is probably a license issue. I believe jooq has a commercial as well the open source license, so the missing dialects are probably in the commercial version. Can you also indicate what license you have?

Comment: @smac89, yes, 3.13.5 is the latest version of that library. I did not read anything about license issues around the dialects, speaking about for example [this](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/sql-dialects/) page or [this](https://blog.jooq.org/tag/sql-dialects/) page.

Comment: [Here](https://www.jooq.org/download/) you go. Scroll down to **Database Support** and you will see what is included in what license. I think their Javadoc includes everything that jooq has to offer, regardless of licensing, but you need to be aware of what you actually get when you choose to download a certain version of the library

Comment: I had not check this page, I did not even seen this, thanks @smac89 for that hint, everything is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc on the jOOQ website](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/) is the Javadoc of the jOOQ Enterprise Edition, which is the most complete Javadoc. Elements that are only available in commercial distributions are annotated with the [`org.jooq.Pro`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Pro.html) annotation, for example [`SQLDialect.SQLSERVER`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.13.x/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#SQLSERVER) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> @Pro
> public static final SQLDialect SQLSERVER
> ```
>
> The SQL Server dialect family.
> This family behaves like the versioned dialect SQLSERVER2017.
>
> Use this family (or its dialects) for SQL Server or Azure SQL Database.
>
> **This dialect is available in commercial jOOQ distributions, only.**

It would make sense to explain this also in the Javadoc of the `SQLDialect` class, right at the top. I've created a feature request to improve this: [#10745](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10745)

The list of supported database products per jOOQ edition can also be found here:
https://www.jooq.org/download/#databases

In order to evaluate jOOQ for SQL Server, you need to download the free jOOQ Trial Edition from that download page. The commercial distributions are not distributed to Maven Central. Some heads-up, use the Maven groupId `org.jooq.trial` instead of `org.jooq` [as documented here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step1/).